# How to build a string concurrently?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

In the MWE (Minimal Working Example) given below, I configure

- `Simulator.CpuBoundOperation("red", 150));` to spin 150 times with red font in a thread-pool thread.
- `Simulator.CpuBoundOperation("green", 550);` to spin 550 times with green font.

I want to get an HTML output consisting of a string of thread ids with alternating red-green numbers because they run concurrently.

Unfortunately, the output shows unwanted result in which all the green numbers printed first  followed by all the red ones. I attempted to increase the iteration but it does not work as well.

How to fix this issue?

## MWE

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Simulator
{
    private static readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    static Simulator()
    {
        string begin = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style='width:500px;background-color:black;font-size:20pt'><p>";
        sb.Append(begin);
    }

    public static void CpuBoundOperation(string color, int n = 50)
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sb.Append($"<span style='color:{color}'>{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} </span>");
        // a white space before </span> is important
    }

    public static new string ToString()
    {
        sb.Append("</p></body></html>");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

class Test
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Work();
        File.WriteAllText("output.html", Simulator.ToString());
    }

    static async Task Work()
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() => Simulator.CpuBoundOperation("red", 150));
        Simulator.CpuBoundOperation("green", 550);
        await t;
        Simulator.CpuBoundOperation("blue");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think, 150 iterations run very very fast, before you call second method, and prints all 1's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operations (apparently) do not take enough time for the background thread to get running before the main thread has completed the green numbers.

Frankly, you're lucky all that happened was that the background task didn't get started until the main thread was waiting. `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe, so if you *had* gotten concurrent execution, you'd have corrupted `StringBuilder`, producing completely wrong output at best, and crashing the program at worst.

It's not clear why you want the text interleaved, but if that's a requirement, you should just do that in a single thread. There's not enough work, at least in the sample program, to justify concurrency anyway. If you really want to guarantee concurrency, you'll have to add logic for the main thread to not start working until the background thread does, but that's a bit of an anti-pattern as it defeats the primary purpose of concurrency: maximizing throughput on computations.

Comment: Yes, adding a `lock` around uses of the `StringBuilder` object would fix the basic thread safety issue. But it would also practically negate any benefit you might obtain from concurrency, because the only significant work (to the extent that there is any significant work) would wind up in the `lock` and prevented from happening concurrently.